# Use Python to find the pathname of "Current" Arcmap

Tags: python, arcmap

I am trying to find the path name of the current ArcMap document that the python script is currently running in.

For Example:

```
"F:\2012\1111\MyArcMap.mxd"
```

I tired using

```
sys.argv[0]
```

as shown here

[Finding script location... dynamically](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19860/finding-script-location-dynamically)

but this gives me the path of the python script not the .mxd

Any thoughts?

Comment: I'll be interested to see any Answers because there seems to be no property on the MapDocument object (http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/00s3/00s30000000n000000.htm) that would help you

Comment: Actually I think there is: Does `MapDocument.filePath` return the expected value?

Comment: Yes that worked.    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")    textElement.text = mxd.filePath

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try [`MapDocument.filePath`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s30000000n000000):

```
>>> mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
>>> mxd.filePath
u'C:\\GISData\\test.mxd'
```